# Oracle SQL Cursor for loop to check dates and assign a value

Tags: sql, date, for-loop, cursor, oracle11g

I'm using SQL Developer for Oracle 11g..

I need to be able to loop through a set of dates,
check to see if the date above or below is = or < or >..

Then assign a trip number that is the same as the one its = to or 
assign a new trip number and then begin a new trip and check again
the next date to see if its = or < or > than the current date..

I think in order to do this I need to use the pl/sql cursor for loop.. 
I've tried to figure it out but its not making much sense to me..

For example, I want the end result to be something like this..

```
ROWID     DATE        TRIP
  1         1-Jan-12    1
  2         2-Jan-12    2
  3         2-Jan-12    2
  4         3-Jan-12    3
  5         4-Jan-12    4
  6         1-Jan-12    1
  7         4-Jan-12    4
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Alex

Comment: Looks like (DATEDIFF(DATE, MINIMUM_DATE) +1) to me...

Comment: @AlvaroGMJ, `datediff` is a SQL Server function and [_requires_ a date part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the correction. I actually know nothing about SQL Server, I have worked with Oracle and MySQL, and I guess I was thinking about the latter when I wrote my comment. In ORACLE, my suggestion would be "date - minimum_date + 1", assuming you get minimum_date beforehand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL Cursor for loop to check between the START_DATE and END_DATE and assign a trip value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145798/oracle-sql-cursor-for-loop-to-check-between-the-start-date-and-end-date-and-assi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop at all!  All you need is the analytic function dense_rank:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by startdate) as trip
from t
```

Comment: I Guess I should clarify this a bit more.. I should have shown two date columns because I am looking to compare bwt two columns of dates one is the begin_date and the other is the end_date..

Comment: @SeattleGray . . . Your comment makes no sense.  Given the first two columns of data, this query produces the output for the "trip" column.  You should post another question that clarifies what you really want, because it seems to be substantially different from this question.

Comment: dense_rank(START_DATE) OVER(order by END_DATE) as tripnum

Comment: @SeattleGray . . . I made a mistake when I typed out the code.  Dense_rank() doesn't take an argument.  There is not space for two dates.  As I said before, you need to ask another question, where you better explain what you need, preferably with examples of input data and result data.

Comment: @SeattleGray, if there's something missing can you update your question with your beginning data and what your expected output is?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the heads up.. I am going to ask a different question.. I was focused on the one column and forgot to include the other one.. again thanks..